# Ubuntu rails install fails on zlib

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, zlib, ubuntu-8.10

I've just moved over to Ubuntu 8.10 as my dev box; it's my first serious foray into Linux as a daily-use OS, and I'm having a hard time getting Rails going.  I have followed a number of tutorials which all seem to work fine, but when I try and use gem install or gem update on anything, I get an error that looks like this:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- zlib (LoadError)
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/spec_fetcher.rb:1
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/commands/update_command.rb:5
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/command_manager.rb:167:in `load_and_instantiate'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/command_manager.rb:88:in `[]'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/command_manager.rb:144:in `find_command'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/command_manager.rb:131:in `process_args'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/command_manager.rb:102:in `run'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:58:in `run'
from /usr/local/bin/gem:21
```

I have (as recommended in the tutorials) installed zlib, zlib1g, and zlib1g-dev.  I've even found a few tutorials on this particular problem (all for flavors other than mine, however) but they didn't help.

I'm on Ubuntu 8.10, ruby version  1.8.8dev gem version 1.3.2

I've tried reinstalling ruby and gems each and separately, to no avail.

Comment: "Ubuntu noob rails install fails on zlib" Wow. That's like the most beautiful poem ever.

Comment: apt-get install zlib1g zlib1g-dev worked for me on Ubuntu 10.04

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441248/rvm-ruby-1-9-1-troubles

Comment: this link also helps
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9727908/cannot-load-such-file-zlib-even-after-using-rvm-pkg-install-zlib

Answer (score 297, accepted):

If you come across this question trying to install Ruby using Ruby Version Manager (RVM) on Ubuntu 10.04 then there are instructions on installing zlib on the rvm web site http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/packages/zlib/

The steps are:

```
rvm pkg install zlib
```

(or 
    `rvm package install zlib` if you get "ERROR: Unrecognized command line argument: 'pkg'"  - older versions of rvm used the verb 'package' instead)

then

```
rvm remove 1.9.1
rvm install 1.9.1
```

Comment: great, same approach worked for me with a minor variation for 1.9.2:
 vm package install zlib ;
 rvm remove 1.9.2-p0 ;
 rvm install 1.9.2-p0 --with-zlib-dir=$rvm_path/usr

Comment: wonderful, i was wondering why rvm wasn't working on debian even with zlib installed via apt

Comment: had the same trouble, finally found this worked for me: `vm package install zib; rvm remove 1.9.2; rvm install 1.9.2 --with-zlib-dir=$rvm_path/usr`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had this same problem. I just had to replace "1.9.1" with "ree" in Ubuntu. +1!

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu 11.04 with 1.9.2  nb: have to use sudo for gem installs after that, e.g. `sudo gem install sqlite3-ruby`

Comment: For those who are still hitting errors after doing this, check `rvm requirements` and follow the instructions for ruby and rvm.  I had to repeat these steps after doing that

Answer (score 53):

I am using Ubuntu 10.04 (Lucid), i wanted to install ruby 1.9.2 because 1.9.1 is not recommended with Rails.  So I downloaded the source for 1.9.2 and unzipped/unarchived it.  my source distro is ruby-1.9.2-p0.  After I unpacked it, I built zlib as follows:

```
cd ruby-1.9.2-p0/ext/zlib
ruby extconf.rb
make
sudo make install
sudo gem install rails
```

that fixed the problem.  This is similar to what other people posted above, but not exactly, so I figured I may as well post exactly what I did to get it going.

Comment: This is the best resource i found. I installed ruby from source without rvm, and get a problem with zlib. This post help alot. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you! Fixes the issue on 1.9.2-p136/Ubuntu 10.04.1.

Comment: Thank you. Fixes the issue on 1.9.2-p180/Red Hat 4.1.2-46 too.

Comment: This worked for Ubnutu 11.04/Ruby 1.9.2-p180. I tried `apt-get install zlib1g zlib1g-dev` but it didn't work (it's possible that `zlib1g-dev` was not installed before I compiled Ruby).

Comment: Seems like you need this even when you install ruby from source. Not sure why it's not installed by default

Answer (score 22):

I have the same problem in CentOS and fix it by executing the following command:

First, I ensure that zlib and zlib-devel exist (like many suggested above).

```
yum install zlib zlib-devel
```

Second, I recompiled and installed the sources of zlib that comes with ruby.

```
cd /home/myname/installers/ruby-1.8.7-p174/ext/zlib/
ruby extconf.rb --with-zlib-include=/usr/include --with-zlib-lib=/usr/lib
make
make install
```

That commands seem to fix the problem, then I execute `gem update --system` and the error with zlib vanished. Then I install rails with gem install rails. Note to mention I had installed gem before, and after recompile and install zlib, I don't recompile neither install gem (actually I don't knew how uninstall it because I don't found a script to do that)

That works for me...hope to you to.

Regards.

Answer (score 13):

try

```
aptitude install zlib1g-dev
```

Then go about your business.

Comment: i actually had to do this before being able to compile the zlib that came with ruby source

Answer (score 8):

I really didn't like any of these answers ... none really focused on the users actual needs and question ... just people telling what they did ... no context and it didn't even work for me ...

So, ..

I'm installing a new box Ubuntu 8.04 LTS 64-bit ...

So, I ...

```
cd ~  
wget ftp://ftp.ruby-lang.org//pub/ruby/1.9/ruby-1.9.2-p180.tar.gz  
tar -xvvf ruby-1.9.2-p180.tar.gz  
cd ruby-*  
./configure  
make  
install  
sudo make install
```

And then I have this problem with ...

```
gem list
```

it doesn't work ... something about zLib not found crap ...

So, I actually READ the README and find that I need to edit a file ...

```
[my ruby source directory]/ext/Setup
```

and UN-COMMENT the line with zLib in it ... by removing the "#" in the first column

Then I run the commands again ... included here for reference ...

```
./configure
make  
install  
sudo make install
```

and all is well ... it's logical ... and is devoid of "rvm" and other ... "just install more stuff to make it work" type solutions.

Joet

Comment: Doesn't help for me. I read the readme as well, and followed it's instructions, but even after I still can't get ruby gems to work, with it still saying no zlib...

Comment: Actually the answer is relevant as this is a common problem when using rvm.  Your answer is more suitable for people who don't use rvm.

Answer (score 7):

Just goto Ruby Source Package , Unzip it.

Goto /your-ruby-dir/ext/zlib

```
ruby extconf.rb
make
sudo make install
```

If the packages are missing it will tell you, mainly libzlib related packages

Regards

Saurabh

Answer (score 6):

```
rvm package install zlib
rvm remove 1.9.1
rvm install 1.9.1
```

That did it. After numerous wild goose chases, I'm glad I found this page.

Comment: FYI - 'package' has been changed to 'pkg' in a more recent version of rvm. See https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/pull/345

Answer (score 4):

yes, and that didn't do the job either.  Got this from another source, this finally did it for me where the other stuff failed.

```
wget http://www.blue.sky.or.jp/atelier/ruby/ruby-zlib-0.6.0.tar.gz
tar xvzf ruby-zlib-0.6.0.tar.gz
cd ruby-zlib-0.6.0
ruby extconf.rb && make
sudo make install
```

Reinstall ruby gems from source

Thanks anyway, guys.

Comment: I had a problem running extconf.rb. Solved it (probably) by installing zlib-devel.

Comment: same here. Tried everything else, and finally blue.sky.or.jp saved me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that Ruby on Ubuntu isn't built against zlib; you'll want to do a source build to install Ruby.  You can do this with `apt-get source -b ruby`

Comment: ok,again, linux noob.  No idea what you just said.  lol.  I mean, I understand the command; but what do I do after that?

Comment: well, now, even that much didn't work.  I got a "Build command 'cd ruby-defaults-4.2 && dpkg-buildpackage -b -uc' failed" error

Answer (score 2):

Did you try apt-get install libzlib-ruby?

Also install rubygems from rubyforge. I don't like the rubygems package in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

On Debian (Squeeze):

libruby contains zlib for ruby amongst all the other stuff you'll need to make ruby work properly on Debian. So...

```
apt-get install libruby
```

Then...

```
cd /usr/local/src/ruby
make clean
make
make install
cd ../rubygems
ruby setup.rb
gem install rails
```

This made it work for me, but your mileage may vary. I did to a slight shotgun approach to zlib before finding that everything needed was covered by libruby.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to download the ruby enterprise deb package on the [phusion](http://rubyforge.org/frs/download.php/51101/ruby-enterprise_1.8.6-20090201_i386.deb) site. And install passenger through the package. Follow the instructions [here](http://www.modrails.com/install.html).
Or you could try the bash script found [here](http://gist.github.com/37213).

Answer (score 0):

When running Rails I would not recommend using Ruby 1.8.8dev. Stick with 1.8.6, preferably the Ruby Enterprise Edition. See this post on [RailsLab](http://railslab.newrelic.com/2009/04/01/the-state-of-the-stack-a-ruby-on-rails-benchmarking-report) what other people are using.

If you insist on going hi-tech, install Ruby 1.9.1.

But in both cases build it yourself or use Marans suggestion.

Comment: This is bad advise, do NOT use 1.9.1 with rails.  1.9.2+ works fine, though.

Comment: That comment was placed 2 years ago... Now 1.9.3 would be the way to go of course.

Comment: sure, I'm fine with that.  But it's important for someone to know it's wrong.