# RVM Ruby 1.9.1 install can't locate zlib but its runtime and dev library are there

Tags: ruby, rubygems, zlib, rvm

Trying to get Ruby 1.9.1 up and running with RVM on a fresh install (fedora).

After doing `rvm install 1.9.1`, the rubygems error logs show that zlib can't be located

> no such file to load -- zlib (LoadError)

However both the zlib runtime and development libraries are installed and up-to-date.

I'm kinda stumped on this one at the moment.

Answer (score 109):

Use rvm to install zlib

https://rvm.io/packages/zlib/

```
rvm package install zlib
rvm remove 1.9.1
rvm install 1.9.1 -C --with-zlib-dir=$rvm_path/usr
```

Edit: The `rvm package` command was renamed to `rvm pkg` in v1.6.25.

Comment: Nice. It took forever to reinstall Ruby, but it worked (with 1.9.2) just fine.

Comment: This step is unnecessary if zlib1g-dev is installed first. See rubiii's solution below.

Comment: This didn't run for me in RVM version 1.8.1. The package parameter must be obsolete. I used "rvm pkg install zlib" and it was fine.

Comment: Slavo: You're right. Seems like `rvm package` was renamed to `rvm pkg`. I'll edit this answer to include the change.

Comment: The apt solution below worked for me, while this did not. I have a Debian linux.

Comment: Use rubiii solution... much easier. sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libreadline5-dev libxml2-dev libsqlite3-dev

Comment: Didn't work for me on CentOS 6.x (I did install zlib first, then removed 1.9.1, then reinstall 1.9.1 with the provided parameter): 


[root@localhost ~]# gem install arachni
ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
    no such file to load -- zlib
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NameError)
    uninitialized constant Gem::Commands::InstallCommand

Comment: I am getting "There is no checksum for 'http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/libpng/zlib-1.2.7.tar.gz' or 'zlib-1.2.7.tar.gz', it's not possible to validate it."

Comment: For those who are still hitting errors after doing this, check `rvm requirements` and follow the instructions for ruby and rvm.  I had to repeat these steps after doing that

Answer (score 63):

You need to install `zlib` before compiling/installing Ruby. If you didn't do this, make sure to remove everything related to Ruby 1.9.1 from your `~/.rvm` folder (so that it will be build from scratch).

Install `zlib` using your favorite package manager:

```
sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev
```

You might also want to install the following packages as they are required by tools like OpenSSL,
Nokogiri, IRB or SQLite:

```
 libssl-dev libreadline6-dev libxml2-dev libsqlite3-dev
```

Then install Ruby 1.9.1 again (nowadays I would suggest to use a newer version):

```
rvm install 1.9.1
```

Watch for "compiling ...". This should take a while. If it doesn't, then Ruby 1.9.1 might still be cached
in your `~/.rvm` folder.

Comment: This worked fine for me, and I rather have stuff installed through the system's package manager than through the "rvm package" thing.

Comment: Because the newer version of libreadline is available it's better to install libreadline-dev or directly libreadline6-dev

Comment: this is the best solution, since it saves you having to re-compile ruby everytime you encounter a gem that requires libssl, libxml, etc. And in fact you might want to add `libxslt1-dev` and `libcurl4-openssl-dev` to the list (nokogiri dependency)

Answer (score 10):

I encountered this problem when trying to:

> gem install **gruff**

What actually worked for me (Ubunut 10.10, ruby MRI 1.8.7) is:

- reading the rvm notes and installing the dependencies for my ruby version

> sudo **apt-get install** build-essential bison openssl libreadline6 libreadline6-dev curl git-core zlib1g zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-0 libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev autoconf

- then following closely the steps described in https://rvm.io/packages/zlib/

> 1. rvm package install zlib
> 2. rvm remove 1.8.7
> 3. rvm install 1.8.7

So basically: **just follow the rvm manual**

Answer (score 3):

In modern version of rvm **package** argument have been replaced **pkg** argument.

Now, in order to install zlib package for rvm need:

rvm pkg install zlib

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Fedora try running:

```
yum install zlib-devel.i686
```

And then try installing ruby 1.9.1 using RVM

```
rvm install 1.9.1
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, you do know that 1.9.1 is *horribly* broken which is why no one uses it seriously, right? The importance this has to the question asked is that many people do not realize this and attempt to use it with such APIs as Ruby On Rails. However, as rubyonrails.org/download states, Ruby 1.9.1 is not supported for use with Rails as it is *broken*.

Answer (score 1):

On the latest Ubuntu (11.10) there is also an issue with readline.

> Readline was unable to be required, if you need completion or history
>   install readline then reinstall ruby.

So my entire rvm and latest ruby install process for ubunutu 11.10 was:

```
# install rvm
sudo apt-get install curl
curl -L get.rvm.io | bash -s stable

# install dependencies
rvm pkg install zlib
rvm pkg install readline

# install additional dependencies -- follow instructions for your distribution/version
rvm requirements

# install ruby
rvm install [ruby-version]
```

I'm posting this for my future reference and in case anyone else bumps into this issue as well.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the solution was very simple: I had forgotten to close/reopen the shell, as rvm setup had instructed me to do.
After I did that, the zlib error was gone and I was able to: gem install bundler