# fedora execute "gem install bundler"

Tags: ruby

I want to use octopress. so i view the "how to" in this website
  http://octopress.org/docs/setup/
  All is successful until type "gem install bundler" in bash-shell
  The output likes the below:

```
[root@litian octopress]# gem install bundler
ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
    no such file to load -- zlib
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NameError)
    uninitialized constant Gem::Commands::InstallCommand
```

I search on the web, and find that may be zlib1g and zlib1g-dev are short
But when i use
yum search zlib1g, the result is no match

i also find this
[Installing Rails Path on Ubuntu with RVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518294/installing-rails-path-on-ubuntu-with-rvm)
so 
i type

```
rvm pkg install zlib
```

the output is

```
Fetching zlib-1.2.5.tar.gz to /usr/local/rvm/archives
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:01:05 --:--:--     0curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
ERROR: There was an error, please check /usr/local/rvm/log//*.log. Next we'll try to fetch via http.
Trying http:// URL instead.
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:46 --:--:--     0^CERROR: There was an error, please check /usr/local/rvm/log//*.log
```

i don't know what to do,now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

remove your current ruby from rvm like `rvm remove 1.9.3`. install zlib `sudo yum install zlib-devel` and reinstall ruby like `rvm install 1.9.3` then `gem in bundler`

Comment: Thanks. It really helps me. Thanks so much

Comment: Hey @Igor Kapkov... I have same issue as the user.. but i dont use rvm.. i installed ruby1.9.2 manually and even after `yum install zlib-devel` its throwing same error.. any ideas???