# zlib library problem related with Virtual Box version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, virtualbox, zlib, rvm

on the last days I had a really annoying problem, that is just now solved, but I'll hope that some of you experienced it and figured out a solution for that.

I created and installed Ubuntu 10.04 on Virtualbox 3.2.0 (installed under Win7-32 bits). On this VM was installed and configured rvm, ruby 1.8.7 and some gems. When tried to  check the list of gems that were installed for the rvm/ruby conditions above, i deal with the following error when execute the following command on the bash:

$gem list
ERROR:  Loading command: list (LoadError)     no such file to load -- zlib

After googling and solutioning several ideas:
- uninstall/install rvm
- uninstall/install ruby 
- reinstall zlib
- create new Vm's

, we brought to an end that the problem was related with the version of Virtualbox used on my system 3.2.0. After install the last version of Virtualbox - v.3.2.8 the problem related with the `zlib library` was solved.

Cheers.
Just to share with you
.stuckme

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a VirtualBox problem. This is to do with RVM installation. I am using same configuration as yours and got issues resolved with this solution.

[RVM Ruby 1.9.1 install can't locate zlib but its runtime and dev library are there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441248/rvm-ruby-1-9-1-troubles)