# how can i install rubygems with rvm ? what is the difference between the two?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3, rvm

I am trying to set up Rails 3.0.3 running on my machine with Ruby 1.9.2. I have installed rvm and used it to install Ruby 1.9.2. What do do next to install the gems I want?

In particular, please give the command to install RubyGems 1.3.6 because Rails 3.0.3 is asking for it specifically. Can rvm install Rails by itself, or will I need RubyGems for that?

Comment: rubygems is a ruby-level tool for managing and packaging different libraries of ruby code. rvm is a shell-level tool for managing different versions of the ruby interpreter.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can install gems with rvm. Use:

```
rvm use 1.9.2 # Make sure you're using the installed version
rvm gem install --version '3.0.3' rails
```

**Updated** to include specific version of the gem.

Comment: but dont i need to install gems first ?  i need gems 1.3.6. how can i get that ?

Comment: also please mention how to install a specified version of rails

Comment: Ruby includes rubygems as part of 1.9; you got it when you typed `rvm install 1.9.2`. I've also included in the answer how to install a specific gem version.

Comment: `ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
    no such file to load -- zlib
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NameError)
    uninitialized constant Gem::Commands::InstallCommand `

Comment: See [this Stack Overflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441248/rvm-ruby-1-9-1-troubles/2808375#2808375) to fix your zlib issues.

Comment: leaving out the version gets the latest stable release

Answer (score 5):

Looks like you already have rails installed, from the way you've phrased the question. To install rubygems-1.3.6 using rvm just make sure your rvm install is updated and you're using the ruby you want, and then use `rvm rubygems 1.3.6` to select that version of rubygems.

```
rvm get head
rvm reload
rvm use 1.9.2
rvm rubygems 1.3.6
```