# ROR Installation "no such file to load"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to Ruby on Rails. I'm trying to install rails on an ubuntu linux platform. I've already installed RVM and ruby. When I type

```
gem install rails --version 3.0.0
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
    no such file to load -- zlib
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NameError)
    uninitialized constant Gem::Commands::InstallCommand
```

Please help me install rails and learn a bit about the command line while I'm at it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

looks like you dont have ZLib installed. try `gem install zlib` and also `apt-get install zlib zlib-dev` if you dont have the system library installed

you need both the .so c-extension files (apt-get)
and the ruby interface to them (gem )

also this may be the same thing as in [Antother Stackoverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769496/ubuntu-noob-rails-install-fails-on-zlib)

Comment: Apparently I have to rvm install package zlib after removing ruby 1.9.2 but when i try to reinstall ruby after the process i get this:     ERROR: Error running 'bunzip2 '/home/tom/.rvm/archives/ruby-1.9.2-p180.tar.bz2'', please read /home/tom/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.2-p180/extract.log       the process continues but it gets stuck in the compiling process.

Comment: what does the log say? what happened to bzip?

Answer (score 2):

I guess you need zlib package to install rails.
try

```
rvm pkg install zlib
```

after that

```
sudo apt-get install zlib1g
```

and then the development package. not sure why but you need it.

```
sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev
```

then remove the current version of ruby because you didn't have zlib when ruby was compiled. type

```
rvm remove 1.9.2
```

(replace 1.9.2 with your version)
and then install it again with

```
rvm install 1.9.2
```

(again your version here)

That's basically it. I had the same error and it worked for me, hope it helps you too.

Answer (score 0):

This has happened to me a few times.  The answers near the bottom should fix it, but unfortunately you will need to remove and then recompile ruby :(
I have never gotten it to work without totally removing ruby.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1494997