# Unable to install rails in ubuntu 11.10. [Zlib error]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, ruby-on-rails-3.1, zlib

I am currently using ubuntu 11.10. I just now installed rvm and ruby 1.9.2. When I try to install rails I get the following error

```
ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
    no such file to load -- zlib
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NameError)
    uninitialized constant Gem::Commands::InstallCommand
```

I tried installing zlib library in many ways but I still get this error and couldn't proceed further.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do the following:

```
 1. install zlib devel (sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev )
 2. cd /path_to_your_ruby_install_directory
 3. cd ext/zlib/
 4. ruby extconf.rb
 5. make
 6. make install
```

After that try to install rails again

After a little research I found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769496/ubuntu-noob-rails-install-fails-on-zlib) that I consider to be more useful for your case.