# rvm, zlib and ruby not working even after following instructions

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm, zlib

I have researched this issue yet the answers found (including here on SOF) have not resolved it

[Ubuntu noob rails install fails on zlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769496/ubuntu-noob-rails-install-fails-on-zlib)

[cannot load such file -- zlib even after using rvm pkg install zlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9727908/cannot-load-such-file-zlib-even-after-using-rvm-pkg-install-zlib)

Going to the "rvm site for zlib" and following the directions still does not work for me.

```
$ gem install redcar

ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
    cannot load such file -- zlib
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NameError)
    uninitialized constant Gem::Commands::InstallCommand
```

Comment: Do you have the zlib development package installed? I'd guess that it is called zlib-dev or something similar.

Comment: yes I have the zlib-dev package (on ubuntu 10.04)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please use the "quick fix" from here https://rvm.io/packages/zlib/

you have to ignore the rest of instructions, they are intended for systems that do not support packages (like osx)

Comment: I've tried the quick fix (including in isolation from the rest of the comments).  I've actually tried that twice, to preclude having made some mistake.

Comment: hfave you installed all the packages listed to be installed ? what system are you running ?

Comment: yes I installed all the packages, as noted above am running  10.04

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9761745/rvm-zlib-and-ruby-not-working-even-after-following-instructions

Comment: then please run `rvm reinstall ${MY_RUBY_HOME##*/}` and gist `$rvm_path/log/${MY_RUBY_HOME##*/}/make.log`

Comment: Ok looks like that suggestion is maybe getting somewhere