# Linux mint mate - ruby 3.0.2 - zlib.so undefined symbol: inflateReset

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, zlib, linux-mint

I've just installed Linux Mint mate 20.2.
I want to work with the last stable version of ruby so I've downloaded [here](https://www.ruby-lang.org/fr/downloads/) Ruby 3.0.2 and followed the given instructions to install it from sources:

```
$ ./configure
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

After this, I've tried to install Rails (I have the same error whatever I've tried to install that way):

```
gem install rails -v 6.0.0.rc1
```

But this command returns the following error:

```
<internal:/usr/local/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require': /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.0.0/x86_64-linux/zlib.so: undefined symbol: inflateReset - /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.0.0/x86_64-linux/zlib.so (LoadError)
```

The packages zlib1g and zlib1g-dev are already on my system.

I've searched the internet for a solution but couldn't find one, is there anyone here that can help me please ?

Comment: I've found the solutions trough this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769496/ubuntu-rails-install-fails-on-zlib?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Get the latest zlib [here](https://zlib.net/)

Make and install it.

After installing the zlib, rebuild your ruby and the source will link to zlib.